# Why my loop return me only "array"

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to return for each vehicule of the API the brand name and the model name

i'm actualy using this loop:

```
$vehiculecount=count($data);
for($x = 0; $x < $vehiculecount; $x++) {
    echo $data[$x];
    echo $data[brand][name];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

That actualy return me only :

```
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array


 ...
```

This is what i'm getting in PHP with curl to an API :

```
{
totalResult: "150",
nbPageList: 2,
createdAt: "2018-05-28T09:23:05+0200",
updatedAt: "2018-05-28T10:55:14+0200",
reference: "5nqts",
reportNumber: 5,
country: "FR",
state: "vehicle.state.parc",
brand: {
reference: "56f50a85cb0f8",
name: "CITROEN"
},
model: {
reference: "57f4d339e38e3",
name: "C3 AIRDREAM BUSINESS"
},
```

I want to get only 'brand''name' for each vehicle for exemple.
Thx a lot for your help !

Comment: use `var_dump()` instead of `echo()`, until you figure out what your data is

Comment: Yes i do it, thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should dump, as debugging purpose, the $data object in your loop.
Then, you should see that inside your loop, to acces to an element by its number, you have to use the indexed access like this :

```
echo $data[$x][brand][name];
```

Also, to access the brand and name index, you have to use string-key index like this : `$data[$x]['brand']['name']`